# Javascript loop trough array of object and return one object containing only keys that have their values changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, key

I have an array of objects I need to loop through and check if the key of the object has different value. If so return this key.

```
const arrayOfObjects = [
  { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 15 } },
  { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "d", age: 15 } },
  { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 20 } }
];
```

expected result should be

```
const result = {
  last_name: true,
  age: true
}
```

PS: each object has always the same number of keys

Comment: "has different value" than what?

Comment: sorry for my poor explanation skills, in the second object last_name has been changed, so needs to be flagged and returned

if the key changes it need to be returned, doesn't matter how many times

Comment: Grab the value of the first item of the array, do a foreach and an if to compare with all the other item's values, if one of them mismatch, set the result as true/false and break the foreach.

Comment: So you're looking for any entry in the array where the "last_name" property has a different value than the very first entry in the array?

Comment: So, you only want to look at the values of the keys under the `item` property in each object? In other words, what happens if there's an element in the array like `{ item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 15 }, foo: "bar" }`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey *"each object has always the same number of keys"*

Comment: @adiga, good point. not sure it's clear which object is being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through the `arrayOfObjects`. Check if current `item`'s keys have different value compared to previous object's `item`. If yes, set that key to `true` in `result`

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [{ item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 15 } }, { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "d", age: 15 } }, { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 20 } }];
const result = {};

arrayOfObjects.forEach(({ item }, i, arr) => {
  if (i === 0) return; // skip the first item
  
  const prev = arr[i - 1].item; // get the previous item
  for (const key in item) {
    if (item[key] !== prev[key])
      result[key] = true
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: if all the values have to be the same, isn't it better perfomance-wise to just pick the value from the first item to compare with everyone instead of getting the previous item?

Comment: Will this work on non-adjacent discrepancies, though?

Comment: @ggorlen I didn't get what you mean

Comment: @ggorlen a discrepancy will not affect the result because this follows a first to last item approach, meaning that you can't have a different pattern like [1, 1] turning into [2, 2], somewhere around the execution there will be a [1, 2] comparison, setting the key to true.

Comment: You're assuming the OP wants difference to the previous, and not to the first.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm assuming OP wants to add a key to `result` whenever a property has a non-unique value. Since every object has `Joe` as `first_name`, it is not added to the output. So, I'm just comparing each key with previous item's key. Comparing each item with the first object's keys will also work as Valga suggested

Comment: Oh yeah, this is actually really clever. If there is any discrepancy, some item will not be equal to its previous and the algorithm will detect it. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `find`. It's more clear

```js
const data = [
    { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 15 } },
    { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "d", age: 15 } },
    { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 20 } }
];

let result = {};

for (var key in data[0].item) {
  if (data.find((el) => el.item[key] !== data[0].item[key])) {
    result[key] = true;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @adiga find should be a bit faster than some? just curious

Comment: `find` gets the object that matches the condition while `some` returns a boolean

Answer (score 0):

You could take a check which looks into the nested object.

```js
function check(source, target, result) {
    Object.entries(source).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') return check(v, target[k], result);
        if (result[k] === undefined) result[k] = true;
        result[k] = result[k] && v === target[k];
    });
    return result;
}

var arrayOfObjects = [{ item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 15 } }, { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "d", age: 15 } }, { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 20 } }],
    result = arrayOfObjects.reduce((r, o, _, [q]) => check(q, o, r), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) where you would group on the key and keep adding the values. Then filter on the size of the set ... if larger than 1 you had more than one value:

```js
const data = [ { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 15 } }, { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "d", age: 15 } }, { item: { first_name: "Joe", last_name: "Dow", age: 20 } } ];

let result = data.reduce((r,{item},i,a) => {
 Object.keys(item).forEach(k => r[k] = (r[k] || new Set()).add(item[k])) 
 return i == (a.length-1) 
 ? Object.keys(r).filter(k => r[k].size > 1).reduce((r,k) => (r[k] = true, r), {})
 : r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```